# I want Zod to return multiple errors for the same input

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

I have a simple password text input, and I want to show multiple errors below the input, but I have noticed that zod only returns one error at a time even if I use superRefine

here are some codes that I did (I have tested more but I don't have them for copying)

Notice that I am not adding any validation on purpose because I want to see an array of errors

```
  password: z.string().superRefine((val, ctx) => {
    ctx.addIssue({
      code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
      message: `test1.`,
    });
    debugger;
    ctx.addIssue({
      code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
      message: `test2.`,
    });
  }),
```

this is what I started with before I realized this won't return me a list of errors

```
  password: z
    .string()
    .min(8, { message: 'min' })
    .regex(/^[A-Z]*$/, { message: 'uppercase' })
    .regex(/\d/, { message: 'number' }),
```

fyi I am using `react`, `react-hook-forms` and `zod`

I am expecting zod to return me a list of errors of a simple password text input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does return a list of errors:

```
import { z } from 'zod';

const ExampleSchema = z.object({
  password: z
    .string()
    .min(8, { message: 'min' })
    .regex(/^[A-Z]*$/, { message: 'uppercase' })
    .regex(/\d/, { message: 'number' }),
});

const testData = { password: 'aaaaa' };

try {
  ExampleSchema.parse(testData);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.issues);
}
```

This outputs

```
[
    {
        "code": "too_small",
        "minimum": 8,
        "type": "string",
        "inclusive": true,
        "exact": false,
        "message": "min",
        "path": [
            "password"
        ]
    },
    {
        "validation": "regex",
        "code": "invalid_string",
        "message": "uppercase",
        "path": [
            "password"
        ]
    },
    {
        "validation": "regex",
        "code": "invalid_string",
        "message": "number",
        "path": [
            "password"
        ]
    }
]
```

The error object contains an `issues` key which I think is what you want.